# Access Google Drive Files from C# Web Application

Tags: c#, .net, web-applications, google-drive-api, access-token

Hi I am having some trouble accessing the Google Drive SDK, mainly the authentication steps.

I have two main pages in my .Net Web app - `Default.aspx.cs` and `WebForm1.aspx.cs`.
In `Default.aspx` I have a `hyperlink` control that takes the user to the `Google authentication page` when they click on the link:

`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile&redirect_uri=http://localhost/GoogleDriveTest/GoogleDriveTest/GoogleDriveTest/WebForm1.aspx&state=/profile&client_id=*CLIENT_ID*&approval_prompt=force`

Once the user is redirected back to the `REDIRECT_URI` (`WebForm1`), I use this piece of code to access the `authorization` code:

```
HttpRequestInfo request = new HttpRequestInfo(Request);
code = Request.QueryString["code"];
```

Now I am stuck. I know I need to now `POST` this code to:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token <insert POST parameters here>
```

But I am completely stuck as to how to do this. I have tried many things, but all I am getting:

```
Server time out error - it failed to connect to the requested server
```

How do I resolve this issue?

---

EDIT 24/09/2012:

With the new release of Visual Studio 2012, they have incorporated OAuth so it takes care of authentication:
http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/videos/oauth-in-the-default-aspnet-45-templates

This means a user can log in to the local web application with an external account such as Google.

Does this mean, once the user is logged in via Google, that I can then grab the Google Drive files that I need? Or is this just for making registration handling easier in the local web application?

Thanks again.

---

Here is my error:

```
[SocketException (0x274c): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond [2404:6800:4008:c01::54]:443]
   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) +251
   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception) +279

[WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context) +6098637
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream() +13
   GoogleDriveTest.WebForm1.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Projects\GoogleDriveTest\GoogleDriveTest\GoogleDriveTest\WebForm1.aspx.cs:101
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207
```

---

SOLVED!!

My issue was that there is a proxy in my workplace that didn't allow any connections to the required URL. So I turned off the proxy in my browser and it bypassed it going directly the the required URL successfully getting the access token :D

Answer (score 0):

[Refer to the QuickStart](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart) (note the .NET tab!) that shows how to do this with the DotNetOpenAuth library.

Note the following line:

```cs
// Retrieve the access token by using the authorization code:
return arg.ProcessUserAuthorization(authCode, state);
```

Comment: Hi bgever thanks for your reply. I have successfully implemented the console application examples that Google have provided. However I need to get it working for a Web Application and after some reading I found out that you cannot use a `NativeApplicationClient` you need to use a `WebServerClient` which does not support that method you mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

The documentation includes a complete web application sample written in C# that you can use as reference:

https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/dotnet

It is an ASP.NET MVC application but the authorization part can be easily reused in a Web Forms application.

For more details about the authorization flow, check the documentation on how to [Retrieve and Use OAuth 2.0 Credentials](https://developers.google.com/drive/credentials)

Comment: Hi Claudio, thank you for your reply. I have already looked into both of those links and found some issues. With DrEdit it seems as though I need a registered domain name but I am only working with localhost. I read a thread about changing the hosts file or something along those lines but didn't seem to work..

Also with your second link, it seems quite complex - I am only doing this in developer mode and don't need to store credentials etc in the database

Comment: If you need a public domain name for your developer machine, you can get a [free Dyn hostname](http://free.domain.name), point it to the public IP of your PC (make sure NAT forwarding is done correctly on you router), and change the exposure of the internal development webserver to be public.